# Difference in free space on 2 mirrored drives?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, apfs

I have two 16 TB external drives, formatted as APFS, attached to my MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.7.

Drive A is mirrored to drive B (and I have verified they actually are mirrors using both ChronoSync and Beyond Compare). Using Disk Utility, I verified that they originally formatted out to the exact same number of bytes. But drive A has 626 GB of free space while drive B has 583 GB, or 43 GB less of free space.

How is this possible? I could maybe understand a small discrepancy, but not 43 GB. Beyond Compare finds a handful of `.DS_Store` files that have trivial differences, but nothing even close to adding up to 43 GB.

Is this explainable by saying that drive B is remapping 43 GB more worth of bad sectors than drive A? If so, how could I verify this? If not, could there be some kind of hidden files that ChronoSync and Beyond Compare don't see? If neither of these, what the heck is going on?

Comment: Keep in mind that the File-System itself requires also disc space to store the management data about all the files. And those data is not directly synced so that differences can occur. May be the one drive had once a large number of small files that were never completely synced to the second drive and later deleted.